# the pronunciation of "gripe"

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gripe?q=gripes) gives IPA symbol /ɡraɪp/ for "gripe" while [Merriam-Webster](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/gripes) gives /ˈgraɪp/.

Both audio clips on them sound like [grape](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grape), at least sound closer to  gr`a`pe than to wh`i`te.

When speaking very fast, do they sound nearly the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gripe -> /ɡraɪp/
Grape -> /ɡreɪp/

This is how they're pronounced in both General American English and Southern British English.

Gripe -> [ɡɹʷaɪp]
Grape -> [ɡɹʷeɪp]

This is how I pronounce both the words (it's a detailed transcription).

- *Grape* has the same vowel as *mate*, *fate*, *weight* -> [eɪ]
- *Gripe* has the same vowel as *might*, *fight*, *white* -> [aɪ]

In most accents, they're distinguishable even in fast speech.

However, there are some accents such as [Aussie accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English) and [Estuary English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary_English) where they *might* sound similar.

In Aussie English, [eɪ] is realised as [ɐ̟ɪ] (almost the same as the vowel in *fight* the + indicates that the vowel is [advanced/fronted](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_articulation#Advanced_and_retracted))

In Estuary English, [eɪ] is realised [ɐɪ] or [ʌɪ] (similar to the vowel in *fight*)